# I don't know why I'm getting this as my output?

Tags: python, algorithm

This program is supposed to iterate through the numbers in an array starting at position 0 and multiply each number with the number before it. For example since 3 is the first element and there is nothing on the left to multiply it by, so it stays unchanged. For the second position you would multiply the 7 by the value to the left of it which is 3, resulting in the 21 being placed in the array where the 7 was. With my math I should be getting [3, 21, 105, 630, 5670] as the output, but I get this instead: [3, 21, 315, 119070, 21266497350]

```
front = [3,7,5,6,9]
temp = 1
for i in range(len(front)):
    print("before mult " + str(temp))
    front[i] *= temp
    print(front)
    temp *= front[i]
    print("after mult " + str(temp))
```

The full output is:

```
before mult 1
[3, 7, 5, 6, 9]
after mult 3
before mult 3
[3, 21, 5, 6, 9]
after mult 63
before mult 63
[3, 21, 315, 6, 9]
after mult 19845
before mult 19845
[3, 21, 315, 119070, 9]
after mult 2362944150
before mult 2362944150
[3, 21, 315, 119070, 21266497350]
after mult 50251545504173002500
```

Comment: What is `temp`? Can you show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  Your posted code makes no attempt to trace the values.  "Explain this code to me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Do the expected work, and ask a *specific* question about your debugging trace.  **Hint:** insert simple `print` calls to report the intermediate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing unnecessary multiplication

```
front = [3,7,5,6,9]
temp = 1
for i, v in enumerate(front):
    temp *= front[i]
    front[i] = temp

print( front )
```